# Google Chrome: switch focus to newly opened tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs, focus

Now that bookmark sync has made it up into the beta channel, I'm trying out Chrome a little more seriously. I'd like to know whether, whenever I middle-click on a link/bookmark to open it in a new tab, there's an option to immediately switch focus to that tab?

If not then is there an extension that can add this behaviour?

**Update:** Just realised that extensions are not enabled in v4 beta.

**Update 2:** Extensions arrived on the beta channel, tabs to the front is now doing its job nicely :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the **Beta-Channel** Version a Shift+Middle-click should do the trick.

For the **Dev-Channel** Version (Extension system):
There is an extension ["Tabs to the front"](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=069d159c6947efa5&hl=en) which opens new Tabs in the foreground.

Comment: I can't install extensions on the beta channel, but that link reveals that shift+middle-click will work until we beta users get extension support